# combinations for SNPs

Tags: r, matrix, combinations

I am new in R programming. I had a matrix with 2029 rows (individuals) and 1129 columns (SNP markers). all the matrix are 1 or 0. I want to calculate all combinations of the snps for each individual as 0*1=1 and 1*0=1 and 0*0=0 and 1*1=0. I wrote by the script by for. But is it possible to write with combn?

example

```
  x1  x2  x3  x4
```

i1    1     0    0    1

i2     0     1    1    0

i3     1      0    0    0

for each i, I should calculate x1×x2, x1×x3, x1×x4, x2×x3, x2×x4, x3×x4 . The result of each should be as i wrote above i.e 1×0=1 and etc. Note this case is not multipication. I mean if one is 0 and the other is 1, then put for me 1.

Ok my matrix is distured after saving. Please imagine a matrix four columns from x1 to x4. Three rows from i1 to i3. 
Put 0 and 1 as input randomly.

Comment: Please post your attempt and desired output with a small example.

Comment: You might also want to add the R tag.

Comment: @Betty , in order to get someone’s attention, you can either reply directly to their answer or use at symbol followed by their username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you have a data frame looking like this as input:

```
df <- data.frame( # as a minimal example
  x1 = rbinom(10,1,0.5),
  x2 = rbinom(10,1,0.5),
  x3 = rbinom(10,1,0.5),
  x4 = rbinom(10,1,0.5)
)
```

First we get all possible SNP combinations (1 per column):

```
cn <- combn(colnames(df), 2)
```

For each combination, we apply a function doing this:
1. We select in df the columns "x" corresponding to a possible combination
2. For each individual (row in df), we sum the two values (returns 0 if 0*0, 1 if 1*0 or 0*1, and 2 if 1*1)

```
gn <- apply(cn, 2, function(x) {
  rowSums(df[, x]) 
})
```

Then we just replace the 2 by 0 to obtain the desired output:

```
gn[gn == 2] <- 0
```

We can finally name the columns with SNPs combinations:

```
colnames(gn) <- apply(cn, 2, paste0, collapse = "*")

gn
```

Output

```
      x1*x2 x1*x3 x1*x4 x2*x3 x2*x4 x3*x4
 [1,]     0     0     0     0     0     0
 [2,]     1     0     1     1     0     1
 [3,]     1     0     1     1     0     1
 [4,]     1     1     0     0     1     1
 [5,]     1     1     1     0     0     0
 [6,]     1     0     0     1     1     0
 [7,]     0     1     1     1     1     0
 [8,]     0     0     0     0     0     0
 [9,]     1     0     0     1     1     0
[10,]     1     0     1     1     0     1
```